# llenar input a partir de seleccion dropdownlist ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Hola compañeros de StackOverFlow, tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo cargar o darle un valor a un input al momento de seleccionar una opción en un select o dropdownlist.[image: Esta es la vista]

mi controlador create es el siguiente:

```
// GET: Collaborators/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var lideres = (from p in db.Collaborators
                                  where p.grupo_lider == "SI"
                                  select p).ToList();

            ViewBag.lideres = lideres.Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.nombres, Text = p.nombres }).ToList();

            ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "compania");
            return View();
        }
```

Parte de mi vista:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lider, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lider, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lideres, "Selleccione un líder", new{ @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lider, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cargo_lider, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cargo_lider, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cargo_lider, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Parte de mi modelo con las partes mas relevantes referente a mi duda:

```
[Display(Name = "Lider")]
public string lider { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Cargo Lider")]
public string cargo_lider { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Cargo")]
public string cargo { get; set; }
```

Explico con exactitud lo que necesito, actualmente mi dropdownList que tiene como modelo `model.lider` muestra los nombres de los usuarios cuyo grupo_lider es igual a `"SI"` en el controlador muestra la consulta que realice, lo que necesito ahora es cargar el `input @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cargo_lider, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })` con el cargo según el nombre o el usuario que se seleccione en el dropdownlist, teniendo en cuenta que ese dato esta en la columna `cargo` de la db.collaborators, y necesito cargarlo en el input con el `modelo.cargo_lider`.

Quedo atento a preguntas, respuestas y demás.

Codigo Actual Ajax:

```
$('#iddropdownlist').change(function () {
            var url = "/Collaborators/BuscarCargoLider?claveLider=" + $('#iddropdownlist option:selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    var lider;
                    if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                        lider= JSON.parse(result);
                    }
                    if (lider!= null ) {                    
                        $('#idinput').val(lider);//cargo debe ser la propiedad de la clase lider donde se almacena el cargo del lider 
                    }                
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error al consultar datos del lider");
                }
            });        
        });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult BuscarCargoLider(string claveLider)
        {
            try
            {
                var lider = (from p in db.Collaborators
                             where p.nombres == claveLider
                             select p.cargo).ToList();

                return Json(lider, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: puedes hacerlo con jquery, usando el evento change del dropdownlist para asignar el valor al input

Comment: Buenas tardes amigo, si expongo la pregunta es porque no se como hacerlo, si pudieras ayudarme con un ejemplo claro seria de bastante utilidad, muchas gracias por comentar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en el controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult BuscarCargoLider(string claveLider)
    {
        try
        {
            var lider = tuconsulta(claveLider);                
            return Json(lider, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//lider es un objeto con la propiedades que tienes en la base de datos, espero ya tengas un objeto asi, la funcion tuconsulta es la que va a ir a buscar los datos del lider a la base de datos la debes de tener en algun lado y sólo mandarla llamar aqui
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

En el view:

```
$('#iddropdownlist').change(function () {
    var url = "/nombreControlador/BuscarCargoLider?claveLider=" + $('#iddropdownlist option:selected').val();
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            var lider;
            if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                lider= JSON.parse(result);
            }
            if (lider!= null ) {                    
                $('#idinput').val(lider.cargo);//cargo debe ser la propiedad de la clase lider donde se almacena el cargo del lider 
            }                
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error al consultar datos del lider");
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: genial, parece que es lo que busco lo probare y califico

Comment: hola, actualmente me esta haciendo la consulta y el resultado lo hace perfectamente, lo unico que falta es que el input cargo_lider se cargue con el value

Comment: has probado que llegue hasta la parte del success?

Comment: Si, actualmente realiza todo el proceso, menos el de poner el value en el input

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (Create:824)
    at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
    at done (jquery-1.10.2.js:8249)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.10.2.js:8792)

Comment: si haces un alert(result) que te imprime

Comment: me sale exactamente el resultado que deseo en el input

Comment: el error esta aqui "if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                        lider = JSON.parse(result);
                    }". acabo de cambiarlo por esto if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
                        var lider = result;
                    } y resulto perfecto, muchas gracias, actualiza tu respuesta y te califico

Comment: solo deja esto if (result!= null && result.length > 0) {                    
                $('#idinput').val(result.cargo);//cargo debe ser la propiedad de la clase lider donde se almacena el cargo del lider 
            }

Answer (score 1):

En la vista:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iddropdownlist').change(function () {
        $('#idinput').val($('#iddropdownlist option:selected').val());
    }
});
</script>
```

Para poner un id al dropdownlist e input

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.lider,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.lideres, "Selleccione un líder", new{@id="iddropdownlist" @class = "form-control" })

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cargo_lider, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="idinput" @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: excelente, pero como sabe el javascript que valor poner en el input?

Comment: Con esta instruccion $('#idinput').val($('#iddropdownlist option:selected')..text()); si usas val() es el valor de elemento selecionado y si usas text() es el text de elemento seleccionado

Comment: en el @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cargo_lider, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) quiero que me aparezca el cargo del lider que seleciono en el dropdownlist, lo que significaria que tengo que al seleccionar enviar un dato y a su vez consultarlo, por ejemplo select cargo where lider = "VALORSELECCIONADO "

Comment: necesitas hacer una llamada ajax para hacer esa consulta